# Google Now change the command

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, google-now

I want to develop a application for Google Now, Google now listens to Microphone for command, when a command is received in microphone, before it goes to google now, I want to change the command through code.

Eg. "Whats the temperature in Chennai tomorrow"?

I want to change this command as "Whats the temperature in Chennai today", then pass this command to Google Now.

I would like to know how to do this

Answer (score 2):

That is not currently possible.  You can see the list of currently available voice commands [here](http://support.google.com/nexus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2842392&topic=2818311&ctx=topic).